# Is there a more powerful transformation than Daemon Prince?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Does anyone know if there is a more powerful transformation, or is Daemon prince the limit, given these beings are not omnipotent? My question is:

**[Q] Is there a further transformation? Maybe a "daemon King" or something appreciated? If the answer is yes, what are the requirements for it?**

**For the answer:**

I'm looking for a transformation of a human or other race, this don't include the gods of Chaos as such, unless their develop process were similar.

Comment: Daemon Prince is kind of the limit. A Chaos God can use the last of its powers to create a Daemon Prince, but then no longer exist as a God. It is also possible for a God to use the last of its power and cease to exist. As far as going the other way it has not been done in 40k to date. I am sure Magnus will be the first to find out any step in becoming something more... We also do not know much of how there came to be any of the Gods of Chaos. As far as we know they just are.

Comment: @Odin1806 The Chaos gods don't cease to exist once they create a Daemon prince. i.e we have Daemon princes of Khorne and Khorne still exists as a god. The gods elevate people to Daemon princes but still exist themselves.

Comment: @Odin1806 unless that's very new fluff... do you have a source?   I've never heard that before and at least in the game books there have always been the potential for multiple daemon princes for any given chaos god.

Comment: Also we have detailed stories about how Slaanesh came to be as a warp manifestation of the Eldar's emotional decadence, so your statement that we don't know how any came to be is just wrong.

Comment: @TommyBs I meant for the main three Gods creation. We dont know about them. We assume they were created similar to Slaanesh, but we don't know for sure. And for the creation of Daemons they use portions of the God's power, which has a limit, as massive as it may be. If you use all of your power to do something there is nothing left and you cease to be. In addition the God can reabsorb that power at any time it wishes. If they dont expend all their power they're fine. I can not remember where I read this initially, which is why i did not fully answer, but I want to say it is in a Chaos codex?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth noting, differing Daemon Princes can have varied power levels... One that has only just received the boon of princedom would probably not be able to contend against one who has been around for hundreds or thousands of years.

Answer (score 7):

#### Daemon Prince is as good as it gets

As far as I know, a mortal can only ascend to [Daemon Prince](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Daemon_Prince) and no further. That's pretty much as good as it gets. That's basically what every servant of Chaos aspires to. I've never read or heard of a mortal ascending to a level above Daemon Prince.

A *Daemon King* would be somthing akin to a [greater daemon](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Daemon). Greater daemons themselves are small slivers of the psyche of the Chaos god they serve so I'm not sure a Chaos god would willingly hand over so much power and a part of it's own being to a mortal.

Comment: You have some oficial source or some source ? :/

Comment: @Gawey my comment from your other question stands here also. When asking a question like _How powerful can someone become?_, you'll never get a clear answer from GW. There is no official source. The best you can hope for is an educated guess.

Comment: @Gawey The demon princes are what physical things become when they get turned into demons but still retrain at least part of their former self (else your body rips open and a demon springs out). Both of that is indicated time and again in the army books and also the novels. So as far as we currently know Daft is right there. The rpg COULD be citated but wouldnt count as an official source though.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Daft Daemon Prince is the most powerful a mortal can hope to become. There is sort of an official source (though soon to be defunct) the pre-8th edition Chaos Space Marine codex talks about how being raised to a Daemon Prince is the "Ultimate ambition" for most champions of Chaos and if they further the cause of their master they are given the "precious gift of Daemonhood" and can serve their master for eternity.

The most infamous of these Daemon princes are the Daemon Primarchs.

Greater Daemons on the other hand are fragments of the Chaos Gods themselves so manifestations of their warp power and aren't created from 'mortals'

The Chaos gods ultimately come around from 'thoughts' and emotions this is why the Emperor was so keen on spreading the Imperial Truth and trying to remove the use of the warp for travel. He wanted to remove human's reliance on it and starve the Chaos gods of their power.

I don't know if this ultimately would have 'killed' the Chaos gods but it certainly would have weakened them. The reason I don't think they can be killed is that even actions seem to create warp entities

If you've read the Horus Heresy novel "Master of Mankind" they do explore this a bit more though is obviously still reasonably vague on the nature of the warp but,

> we know that the first murder ever committed in cold blood actually creates a daemon manifestation in the warp that can never be killed - due to the emotions involved. So it is thoughts and emotions that create this.

Ultimately the Emperor wanted to remove the reliance on the warp so he could better manage/guide the emergence of human psykers so that the Warp wasn't as big a risk to mankind